# Why do I get an error when using HttpContext?

Tags: c#, html, xml

I'm working on a code to make a website with songs, but i'm getting an error when using this code:

```
ds.ReadXml(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(filepath));
```

the error code is: **CS0103: The name 'HttpContext' does not exist in the current context**

My SongMethods.cs code is:

```
using System.Data;
using System;
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for Class1
/// </summary>
public class Pokoes
{
public Pokoes()
{
    //
    // TODO: Add constructor logic here
    //
}
public DataSet GetAllSongs(string filepath)
{
    DataSet ds =new DataSet("playlist");

    DataTable dtSongs =new DataTable("song");

    DataColumn dcId = new DataColumn("id");
    DataColumn dcTitle = new DataColumn("title");
    DataColumn dcArtist = new DataColumn("artist");
    DataColumn dcYear = new DataColumn("year");
    DataColumn dcGenre = new DataColumn("genre");
    DataColumn dcFile = new DataColumn("file");

    dtSongs.Columns.Add(dcId);
    dtSongs.Columns.Add(dcTitle);
    dtSongs.Columns.Add(dcArtist);
    dtSongs.Columns.Add(dcYear);
    dtSongs.Columns.Add(dcGenre);
    dtSongs.Columns.Add(dcFile);
    ds.Tables.Add(dtSongs);

    ds.ReadXml(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(filepath));

    return ds;
}

}
```

My index code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

@using System;
@using XmlCrud.App_Code;

@{
SongMethods mySongMethods = new SongMethods();
string filePath = Server.MapPath(@"~\App_Data\playlist.xml");
DataSet ds = mySongMethods.GetAllSongs(filePath);
}
<html>
<head>
<title>XmlCrud</title>
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel"stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<br /><br />
      <table class="table-bordered">
          <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Artist</th>
            <th>Year</th>
            <th>Genre</th>
            <th>File</th>
           </tr>

          @foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables["song"].Rows)
          {
              <tr>
                  <td>@dr["id"]</td>
                  <td>@dr["title"]</td>
                  <td>@dr["artist"]</td>
                  <td>@dr["year"]</td>
                  <td>@dr["genre"]</td>
                  <td>@dr["file"]</td>
              </tr>
          }
      </table>
 </body>
 </html>
```

My playlist.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<playlist>
 <song>
<id>1</id>
<title>if i can't</title>
<artist>50 cents</artist>
<year>2005</year>
<genre>rap</genre>
<file>link</file>
</song>
<song>
<id>2</id>
<title>time in a bottle</title>
<artist>jimmy croche</artist>
<year>1973</year>
<genre>accoustic</genre>
<file>link</file>
</song>
</playlist>
```

we have asked one of our teachers but he couldn't help us with the problem at the moment, so we hope some people in here can.

Comment: The error is telling you that you never declared the variable `HttpContext` anywhere for the system to know what it is. If you have a sample app that's already got a successful implementation of `HttpContext`, try looking through it for where the variable is defined, and see if you can replicate that. Or, try reading HttpContext documentation. Or, try searching github for code snippets that will bring you to a project with useful code examples.

Comment: @NateW You wouldn't declare an HttpContext, except perhaps as part of a unit test. It's an instance provided by the ASP.NET framework.

Comment: Thanks @mason, I knew generally what the error message meant, but I'm not familiar with this aspect of programming, so I couldn't provide the correct solution, merely an interpretation.

Comment: Should be : ds.ReadXml(filepath); The mapping is done in the HTML and doesn't need to be done again.

Answer (score 0):

HttpContext is part of the System.Web namespace, so add

```
using System.Web;
```